# xpath html get specific tag element

Tags: html, xpath

I searched and tried several solutions for this problem but none of them worked,

this my situation html:

```html
<div class="entry">

<p align="center"><span ><b>CAT-1</b></span></p>

<p align="center">car-1 <a href="" target="_blank" >link</a> </p> //need this
<p align="center">car-2 <a href="" target="_blank" >link</a> </p> //need this
<p align="center">car-3 <a href="" target="_blank" >link</a> </p> //need this


<p align="center"><span><b>CAT-2</b></span></p>

<p align="center">car-1 <a href="" target="_blank">link</a> </p>
<p align="center">car-2 <a href="" target="_blank">link</a> </p>
<p align="center">car-3 <a href="" target="_blank">link</a> </p>

</div>
```

i want to extract just `a href` they are mentioned with `//need this`

I'm already use:

```
$xpath->query( "//p[@align='center']//a[@target='_blank']/text()" );
```

but its extract all `a href`

is there any way to  get it? even though include span  cat-1 no probleme, jsut need h href inside it

Comment: all hrefs are empty in your input

Comment: yes i know ,just for explaine

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath to fetch required text content:

```
//p[@align='center']//a[@target='_blank']/text()[following::b[.='CAT-2']]
```

This with exclude links that follows after paragraph with `"CAT-2"` text

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the output you get?

Comment: nothing has changed I get it all tag, what about you is it done?